# Update table with using NEWID() function

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
CREATE TABLE Products(Id INT, Name CHAR(100), DefaultImageId INT NULL);

INSERT INTO Products (Id, Name, DefaultImageId) VALUES(1, 'A', NULL);
INSERT INTO Products (Id, Name, DefaultImageId) VALUES(2, 'A', NULL);
INSERT INTO Products (Id, Name, DefaultImageId) VALUES(3, 'A', NULL);
INSERT INTO Products (Id, Name, DefaultImageId) VALUES(4, 'A', NULL);
INSERT INTO Products (Id, Name, DefaultImageId) VALUES(5, 'A', NULL);
INSERT INTO Products (Id, Name, DefaultImageId) VALUES(1, 'B', NULL);
INSERT INTO Products (Id, Name, DefaultImageId) VALUES(2, 'B', NULL);
INSERT INTO Products (Id, Name, DefaultImageId) VALUES(3, 'B', NULL);
```

In general, I would update a table randomly like the following scripts.

```
update a
    set DefaultImageId=1
from Products as a
where name = 'A' 
and id in (
    select top 2 id
    from Products as b
    where a.name = b.name
    order by newid()
)
```

However, I get some issue. It would update more/less then 2 rows. I try execute the following scripts many times for debug.
The results are not always only two records. If I remove the order by `newid()`, the number of output result will be fine. It seems like the problem in `newid()`. How can I solve this problem? Thanks

```
select * 
from Products as a
where name = 'A' 
and id in (
    select top 2 id
    from Products as b
    where a.name = b.name
    order by newid()
)
```

Comment: this is working correct per your query. first thing, we use newid() to generate a unique guid, second thing we order by on some existing column, but you used newid() which is wrong. Please use any existing column with order by.

Comment: @ManojKS if i use any existing column with order by, where should i put newid()?

Comment: I don't understand, what is use of newid()?. As I said, we use newid() to get new guid which can be use as an identifier of row like primary key.

Comment: run query select NEWID() and see the result. There is not significance to use newid with order by

Comment: @ManojKS I hope get the id randomly and update their rows. What should I do? Thanks

Comment: @ManojKS When using NEWID() in ORDER BY clause, the output will be RANDOMLY sorted each time the query executed.

Comment: @VahidFarahmandian please take up query from martin. Actually he raised the query. I just give my view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
UPDATE U SET DefaultImageId = 1
FROM(
      SELECT TOP 2 * FROM dbo.Products WHERE Name = 'A' ORDER BY NEWID()
) AS U
```

However if you filter out the `DefaultImageId=1` in inner query, it would be even better too. You should note that in this case, the inner query might produce less than 2 records.

```
UPDATE U SET DefaultImageId = 1
FROM(
      SELECT TOP 2 * FROM dbo.Products WHERE Name = 'A' AND DefaultImageId <> 1 ORDER BY NEWID()
) AS U
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this

This query selects 2 rows at random.

```
with top_2_cte(id, [name]) as (
    select top 2 id, [name] 
    from Products 
    where name='A' 
    order by newid())
select a.* 
from Products a
     join
     top_2_cte ttc on a.Id=ttc.id
                      and a.[Name]=ttc.[name];
```

Update statement

```
;with top_2_cte(id, [name]) as (
    select top 2 id, [name] 
    from Products 
    where name='A' 
    order by newid())
update a
    set DefaultImageId=1
from Products a
     join
     top_2_cte ttc on a.Id=ttc.id
                      and a.[Name]=ttc.[name];
```

Comment: How can i apply with update statement? I tried to replace from "select a.*" to "update a
set DefaultImageId=1". It is not work. Thanks

Comment: There is not significance to use newid with order by

Comment: @ManojKS run the code repeatedly and you'll see it randomly selects 2 rows.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're just looking for a simple `JOIN` as

```
UPDATE A
SET DefaultImageId = 1
FROM Products A
JOIN 
  (
    SELECT TOP 2 Id, Name
    FROM Products B
    ORDER BY NEWID()
  ) B ON A.Id = B.Id AND A.Name = B.Name;
```

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=2f061199bb15c1cb33d42fc54e15a0fb)

Answer (score 0):

**SQL SERVER BUG:**

I think you just hit the following SQL server bug, that is still under review since 2018.

https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server/suggestions/33272404-cte-containing-top-and-newid-producing-incorrect

**WORK AROUND:**

The only thing that seems to work, based on my stesting, is if you eliminate the outside reference from the subquery, things works as expected. You can eliminate the outside reference by doing any of the following as suggested by others here.

Option 1: Keeping the query as-is, except hard-coding the filter criteria inside the subquery instead of using an outside reference:

```
SELECT ...
FROM t1 
WHERE 
  t1.id IN (SELECT TOP 2 id subquery with NO outside reference WHERE name = 'A' ORDER BY ORDER BY newid() )
  AND t1.name = 'A'
```

....

Option 2: Using a `JOIN` with proper `ON` matching criteria instead of using an outside reference inside the subquery:

```
SELECT ...
FROM t1 
     INNER JOIN (SELECT TOP 2 id subquery with NO outside reference ORDER BY newid() ) t2 ON t1.id = t2.id and t1.name = t2.name
WHERE
   t1.name = 'A'
  ....
```

OR

**DETAILS:**

Based on my testing, when all of the following are aligned, the SQL Engine returns an unpredictable result:

- An outside table is referenced inside the subquery (or through CTE) as a filtering criteria
- `NEWID()` function is used in the `ORDER BY` with a `SELECT TOP` statement (It does NOT happen with other non-deterministic functions like `RAND()` for example. Something specific to `NEWID()`)
- The `SELECT TOP` statement uses a number less than the number of records exists in that table

This seems to throw off the SQL engine. The result changes at every run: The number of records returned varies at every run between zero records and max number of records that would have been returned if `SELECT TOP` was not used.

The query plan does not make sense at all. See the screenshot here. `TOP N` returns more than it is supposed to and `id IN ()` predicate returns random number of records (zero in this example). How could that be possible? I have no clue. Also, note that the `id IN ()` predicate is applied before the left table scan, which shouldn't happen. I think the unreliable result has something to do with that. We'll have to wait until SQL Server team fixes the bug to be able write the queries the way you wrote.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As you are using Correlated subquery, where outer query `name` is referred by subquery `name`, you are getting different result set.

I would suggest you to use the `name` parameter twice to avoid this problem.

```sql
select * 
from Products as a
where name='A' 
and id in 
   (select top 2 id
    from Products as b
    where b.name = 'A'
    order by newid())
```

Similarly, for `update` also, you change the query

```sql
update a
    set DefaultImageId=1
from Products as a
where name = 'A' 
and id in (
    select top 2 id
    from Products as b
    where b.name = 'A'
    order by newid()
)
```